# SSL Configuration on System i

Tags: ssl, ibm-midrange

I have written a delphi application that allows a user to define a query and run it over a DB2 database on an IBM System i using a TADOQuery component with the IBM DB2 OLE DB Provider.

We now have a requirement that the user be allowed to secure the connection using SSL if they so wish. I know that I can pass a value of "SSL=TRUE" into the connection string for the OLE DB Provider. The problem that we're having is setting up SSL on the System i server so that we can set up our test environment.

I can't find any instructions for securing the database application on a System i to use SSL. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Setting up SSL on the iSeries](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r1/ic2924/index.htm?info/rzain/rzainoverview.htm)

Comment: I've already found and followed through that link and was still coming up short. However, we've had some feedback from IBM and managed to get everything up and running, so you weren't far off!

Comment: Would be good if you could describe a bit of the feedback from IBM. As you mentioned that link doesn't directly address your question.